# how to define the URL of the media file in UPnP media server using the CyberLinkforjava API?

Tags: android, upnp

how to define the URL of the media file in UPnP media server using the CyberLinkforjava API? I use the CyberLinkforjava APIs to create a DMS, but I know how to define the URL of the media file. I read the clinkjavaproguide.pdf file, but there is not any information about it. Is there any material about it?

Answer (score 1):

The URL is absolutely up to you, that is your implementation of the DMS. What you present as an URL for the media file (when DMR browses your DMS), you then must be able to give upon GET request from the DMR.

Cyberlink is a generic UPnP framework, which can be used for implementing any UPnP DCP (Device Control Protocol). Cyberlink itself does not provide any specific DCP implementation. DMS is a `MediaServer` DCP and you need at least `ContentDirectory` service for the URL operation. Quick googling yields that [x360mediaserver](https://code.google.com/p/x360mediaserver/source/browse/trunk/x360MediaServer/x360mediaserver/upnpmediaserver/upnp/contentdirectory/ContentDirectory.java) is based on cybergarage, so go get some ideas :) Reading the [UPnP spec](http://upnp.org/resources/upnpresources.zip) for `MediaServer.ContentDirectory` can't hurt either. In chapter "Theory of Operation" you have a simple example of how the URL may look.